# illegal start of expression, coin flip java

Tags: java

```
public class Coin
{
    /**
     * Creates a new Coin object.
     */
    public Coin()
    {
        private boolean headup;
        public void flip ()
        {
            headup = Math.random() < 0.5;
        }
        public boolean isHeads()
        {   
            return headup;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            if (headup)
                return "Heads";
            else
                return "Tails";
        }
    }
}
```

can someone tell me what did i do wrong for my code?

Answer (score 1):

You've nested methods inside of a constructor, something not legal in Java.

Solution: get those methods out of the constructor and out on their own in the class.

```
public class Coin {

   private boolean headup;

   public Coin() {

   }

   public void flip() {
      headup = Math.random() < 0.5;
   }

   public boolean isHeads() {
      return headup;
   }

   public String toString() {
      if (headup)
         return "Heads";
      else
         return "Tails";
   }
}
```

Comment: should i take out the boolean and void. put them on the top?

Comment: @Michael: your comment confuses me. What do you mean by "take out the boolean and void. put them on the top"?

Comment: i mean for private boolean headup should i move it to the line before public coin?